# How does Git determine what objects need to be sent between repositories?

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull, git-fetch

I have looked [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols) but couldn't quite figure out the things I was wondering about: how does `git push` or `git pull` figure out what commit objects are missing at the other side?

Let's say we have a repository with the following commits: (letters stand in for SHA-1 IDs, `d` is `refs/heads/master`)

```
a -> b -> c -> d
```

The remote, in contrast, has these:

```
a -> e -> f -> g
```

According to the git document, the remote would tell us that its `refs/heads/master` is at `g`, but since we don't know that commit, that doesn't actually tell us anything. How is that enough to figure out the missing data?

---

In the other direction, the document says:

> At this point, the fetch-pack process looks at what objects it has and responds with the objects that it needs by sending “want” and then the SHA-1 it wants. It sends **all the objects it already has** with “have” and then the SHA-1. At the end of this list, it writes “done” to initiate the upload-pack process to begin sending the packfile of the data it needs:

this explains how the remote would determine what data to send, but wouldn't this impact pull performance on repositories with many objects? Otherwise, what is it that is actually meant in the text?

---

Apparently the way of data transfer is very different depending on the direction (push vs pull). What and how are the challenges met by this design choice, and how am I to understand their descriptions in the document?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The magic is in the IDs.  A commit ID is made up of many things, but basically it's a [SHA-1 hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) of this.

- Content (everything, not just the diff)
- Author
- Date
- Log message
- Parent IDs

Change any of these and you need to create a new commit with a new ID.  Note that the parent IDs are included.

What does this mean for Git?  It means if I tell you I have commit "ABC123" and you have commit "ABC123" we know we have the same commit with the same content, same author, same date, same message *and same parents*.  Those parents have the same ID so they have the same content, same author, same date, same message, *and same parents*.  And so on.  If the IDs match, *they must have the same history*, there's no need to check further down the line.  This is one of Git's great strengths, it is woven deeply into its design, and you cannot understand Git without it.

A pull is a fetch plus a merge.  `git pull origin master` is `git fetch origin` plus `git merge master origin/master` (or `rebase` with `--rebase`).  A fetch looks something like this...

```
remote @ http://example.com/project.git

                  F - G [bugfix]
                 /
A - B - C - D - E - J [master]
                     \
                      H - I [feature]

local
origin = http://example.com/project.git

                  F - G [origin/bugfix]
                 /
A - B - C - D - E [origin/master] [master]
```

- [local] Hey remote, what branches do you have?
- [remote] I have bugfix at G.
- [local] I also have bugfix at G!  Done.  What else?
- [remote] I have feature at I.
- [local] I don't have feature nor I.  What's the parents of I?
- [remote] I's parent is H.
- [local] I don't have H, what's H's parents?
- [remote] H's parent is J.
- [local] I don't have J.  What's J's parents?
- [remote] J's parent is E.
- [local] I have E!  Send me J, H and I please.
- [remote] Ok, here they come.
- [local] *adds J, H and I to the repo and puts origin/feature on I* Ok, what else do you have?
- [remote] I have master at J.
- [local] I have master at E, you already sent me J. *moves origin/master to J*.  What else?
- [remote] That's it!
- [local] Kthxbi

And now local looks like this...

```
local
origin = http://example.com/project.git

                  F - G [origin/bugfix]
                 /
A - B - C - D - E [master] - J [origin/master]
                              \
                               H - I [origin/feature]
```

Then it will do `git merge master origin/master` to finish the pull, which will fast forward to J.

A push is similar, except the process goes in reverse (local sends commits to the remote) and it will only fast-forward.

This is what [Pro Git refers to as "the dumb protocol"](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols#The-Dumb-Protocol) and is used when your remote is a simple HTTP server. [The Smart Protocol](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols#The-Smart-Protocol) is what is used more often, is far less chatty, and has many optimizations.  But you can see how either can be terribly efficient.  There's no need to communicate the whole history, they just need to send 20 byte hash keys until they find a common ancestor.

Here's some sources and further reading.

- [Pro Git - Git Transfer Protocols](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols)
- [libgit2 fetch example](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/ex/HEAD/network/fetch.html)

Comment: Your answer is great, thank you! If you don't mind, I'm particularly interested in how to avoid the many round trips. Is it simply a matter of eagerly sending e.g. up to 50 hashes (<1kb), or is there a more theoretical, algorithmic mechanism that can determine more quickly if a commit is known?

Comment: Also, if you happen to have any sources for your answer, these would be great. My concern was more "implementing a git-like sync mechanism" so I'm fully satisfied, but a future reader who's looking for "how git's syncing is implemented in detail" might appreciate it.

Comment: @SillyFreak I added a couple references to further detail. The conversation example is how I teach it conceptually, what Pro Git calls ["The Dumb Protocol"](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols#The-Dumb-Protocol). You want to look at ["The Smart Protocol"](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols#The-Smart-Protocol) for a more efficient example.

Comment: The Smart protocol is what I was looking at, quoting from, and asking for clarification about in the first place. But I will look into the example code, thank you.

Comment: @SillyFreak I think I understand the Smart Protocol now. If you ask specific questions about it I might be able to help. Just link them here so I'm sure to see them.